# Installing earlier version of node results in a 401 unauthorized errror

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Running npm inistall -g npm@7.20.2 returns this.

```html
$ npm install -g npm@7.10
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.fury.io/npm

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-17T14_31_43_841Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: change your mirror

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you mean by 'mirror'.

Comment: Your NPM server is 'fury.io'. Use the official registry/server.

Comment: [See `registry`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/registry)